# Can't close single view in react native ios

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

new here to react native.  I am using the exact code that is in the expo imagePicker guide (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/) and I am unable to get the image picking UI in iOS to be on top.

```
const _pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
```

My modal:

```
<Modal>
  isVisible={this.state.isModal5Visible}
  onBackdropPress={() => this.setState({ isModal5Visible: false })}
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
    <Button  primary style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent:'flex-start'}}
                    onPress={this._pickImage}
      >
    <Icon name='ios-book' />
    <Text style={ Platform.OS === 'ios' ? {fontSize:16} : {fontSize:12,paddingLeft:4} }>Gallery</Text>
    </Button>
  </View>
</Modal>
```

What happens here is that my view is staying on top of the image picker UI on iOS only, not on Android:

[image]

When I add a close event, it closes both the view and the image picker UI.  How can I only close this view?

Comment: Try using both condition in same button. 
`onPress={this._pickImage(); this.state.isModal5Visible()}`

Comment: isModal5Visible is not a function.  It's a property.  The way I close this modal in other buttons is I use this.setState({ isModal5Visible: false }) And that works.  But when I use it for this button, it closes both windows.

Comment: but if you don't close this modal then image picker modal is always appear in background. You should close it first and in same time open the image picker modal.